# Strange issue for 'Paint.setARGB'

Tags: android, paint

if you want to set color for paint, you have two methods to use:

Method1:   `paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);`

Method2:   `paint.setARGB(255, 100, 100, 0);`

Use the above methods, draw a yellow cycle in android. You will find that 'paint.setARGB() is different from paint.setColor() ',

use Method1 you will get a yellow cycle. (hopeful result)

use Method2 you will get a dim_yellow cycle, it's very strange,

Please give me some good suggestions if you have met this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, these are two different colors:

[image]
**Color.YELLOW**
Hex: FFFFFF00
ARGB: 255, 255, 255, 0

[image]
**Your color**
Hex: FF646400
ARGB: 255, 100, 100, 0

Change `paint.setARGB(255, 100, 100, 0);` to `paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 0);` if you want the identical color.

Comment: Thank you very much, It's my carelessness.

Comment: I use the 'DigitalColor Meter' tool of mac, I selected 'RGB as Percentage'

Answer (score -1):

Yellow -> Red:255 Green:255 Blue:0 Alpha:100